# Delphi applications considered 'dangerous' by Google Chrome

Tags: security, delphi, google-chrome, delphi-2009

I often produce mathematical software in Delphi 2009, and publish it on my web site. However, the last year or so, Google Chrome has started to consider a small (but increasing!) number of my EXEs 'harmful', and Google Chrome refuses do download them.

For example, today I wrote a program that visualises the [Lorenz attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system). You can find it at https://specials.rejbrand.se/chaos/lorenz/; it's lorenz.exe.

When I use Google Chrome to download this EXE, the following prompt appears:

[image: Screenshot of prompt in Google Chrome]

(Yeah, I actually did try it three times...)

This is Swedish, and the text says "%s is harmful and has been blocked by Chrome". The button says "Remove permanently", and the drop-down menu doesn't offer any other actions (like "I know the file is safe, please let me have it").

Obviously, this is kind of a problem. As far as I know, the EXEs are perfectly safe. At least the code I have written is not harmful in any way, but I suspect there is a theoretical possibility that the Delphi compiler has started to add harmful code behind my back.

**Questions**

1. Is there something harmful about my EXEs?
2. Is there some way to make Google Chrome not block my EXEs?

Comment: Considered dangerous? Perhaps Chrome detected too many gotos! ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"*Is there something harmful about my EXEs?*"

No.

Here's a link to the results of [Jotti](http://virusscan.jotti.org/en)'s malware scan (which results with: 22 out of 22 scanners "found nothing"):

http://virusscan.jotti.org/en/scanresult/df25dbecfccc5d10862f52236d664d48d0c72058

The link to [virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/) scan (detection ratio = 0/53):

https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/51d9d637a17f5876c371e5eec164e1dc48a35c56900a3235a9c656d10687814a/analysis/1408587813/

*"Is there some way to make Google Chrome not block my EXEs?"*

One option is to make it block nothing, evidently it's crap anyway. The option is in the "privacy" section in "advanced settings", here are the instructions:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/4412392?p=ib_download_blocked&rd=1

Otherwise, you can check what google thinks about safety of your site:

http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=rejbrand.se

The report seems to be somewhat indeterminate. Here's a quote (for rejbrand.se):

> **Has this site hosted malware?** 
>   
>  Yes, this site has hosted malicious
>   software over the past 90 days. It infected 0 domain(s), including .

Presumably you can also [request a site review](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/168328) in the security issues of google webmaster tools. But apparently it's [not always fruitful](http://portforward.com/virus_help/chrome.htm). That last link also suggests there's a way to send samples to google hoping that they would analyze better (AFAICT [it's not part of webmaster tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3258249?hl=en)), but this might not turn out to be practical depending on the number of executables/versions you produce.

Comment: As @SertacAkyuz pointed out the main reason why Google is blocking file transfers from that site is that in the last 90 days there was malicious activity detected on the site for 19 times. Othervise a general note to you is that instead of placing executables directly to the web zip up your programs as this generally raises less suspision for various automated scanners.

Comment: I did have a look at this 'site review', but didn't really like it. On that page, Google doesn't even pretend there is a possibility of a false positive. Instead, they seem 100 % certain that their automatic system is accurate. Indeed, they tell the webmaster to remove the malware and then request a new review. But I cannot remove any malware from my sites, because there isn't any!

Comment: Sertac, I could request a revalidation of my domain without first removing any of my EXEs, but Google is very clear that one *must* "remove the malware" before one makes such a request, so by making such a request, I will be violating Google's instructions. And I am afraid this will cause Google to block my entire site... (Indeed, in order to submit this request, one has to explain what one has done in order to resolve the malware issue. I don't really dare to write "I have done absolutely nothing".)

Comment: @Andreas - i don't think the result would be any different after a site review, the site itself doesn't seem to be listed and we know this is not the result of any executable scan. I would suggest you to try to identify suspicious pages from the webmasters tools, maybe it's some external links causing this. Note that your host is flagged, which may also contribute.

Comment: I don't think I have anything 'suspicious' on my sites. And the webmaster's tools doesn't complain about anything except these EXEs. How do you know my host (Loopia is Sweden's largest and most trusted web hosting provider) is 'flagged'?

Comment: Sorry, figured out the last part myself using your A.

Answer (score 9):

I could reproduce this behavior with Chrome with your original EXE.

`Is there some way to make Google Chrome not block my EXEs?`

I can confirm that after I digitally signed it (with my company's [signing code](http://www.thawte.com/resources/getting-started/code-signing-faq/) certificate) Google Chrome downloads this file without any issues. This is the most efficient (maybe the only) way to avoid this kind of problems.

Another quick solution is to pack the EXE with `RAR`. Chrome downloaded it with no problem.

Surely this is a False positive "detection" with Google Chrome. My Antivirus (NOD32) did not 
found any problem, and other browsers did not have any issues with your EXE.

NOTE also that Your domain might have issues (flagged) as @Sertac Mentioned. If I download your original EXE from my website the error message is `%s is not comonly downloaded and could be dangerous.` Same goes for any other EXE I uploaded to MY site. (You still have an option to "Keep" the file)

See also here: [Google Chrome Browser Will Block Dangerous Downloads](http://www.pcworld.com/article/224423/chrome_browser_will_block_dangerous_downloads.html)
Specially this:

> As welcome as the new features are, Chrome is in the unusual position
>   of playing catch up to Internet Explorer 9, which features an arguably
>   superior method of blocking potentially malicious downloads.
>   Microsoft's SmartScreen Application Reputation rates downloads in
>   three ways: whether they're digitally signed, the reputation of the
>   author, and--arguably most importantly--how many times the file has
>   been downloaded by others.

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly common problem, actually.  Because Delphi makes software development easy and has no external runtime dependencies, it tends to get used for writing malware, unfortunately.  And so some virus scanner heuristics that are supposed to detect malware instead end up detecting parts of the Delphi RTL.

The best thing to do is to do a bit of research and find out how Chrome is making this determination, and then send the people behind the virus scanner giving the false positives a copy of your EXE(s) with an explanation that this is a false positive and needs to be fixed.

Comment: what if using an digital certificate? Could it stop that?

Comment: In my experience where I work, our software's installer has a digital signature, yet Chrome still likes to block it (although it at least gives the option to keep the file anyway).

Comment: @eelias Malware authors can sign applications too

Comment: @David, issuing a valid and verified certificate is not an easy task for a random Malware author. It took quite a long process until the certificate issuer (in our case "thawte") issued a certificate for our company. unless the author actually steals your certificate spc/pvk/pwd files. which can be later flagged of course.

Comment: @kobik by the time the stolen cert gets revoked the damage can be done. I doubt that good quality anti-malware sw white lists files because they are signed.

Comment: @David, the rating first priority is (usually) by the digital signature AFAIK. or else they are useless.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes you right, it is like that SafeForScripting that were used for ActiveX components, anyone could expose that interface assuring the component was safe, even a malware author.. but that stopped IE asking for authorization.

Answer (score 2):

I have equally been frustrated by this warning, and without going into a rant about how ridiculous the whole thing is, I will share the solution that worked for me.

I have found that double zipping got rid of the warning right away- zip your files, then zip the resulting zip file, the warning will disappear upon downloading.

The user will have to unzip 2 files to get to your files, but that is a much lesser inconvenience than the dangerous warning.